# Using more than one Geoip2 (MaxMind) Database in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to use more than one database in the same Python script and query these DB to have a nice geolocation output. Unfortunately I haven't found something that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I created this script and share it here if anyone needs it.

```
import geoip2.database
import geoip2.errors
import ipaddress
import subprocess

# Launch databases updater program
subprocess.call(['pathto/geoipupdate.exe'])

# Create reader objects for three databases
reader = geoip2.database.Reader('C:/ProgramData/MaxMind/GeoIPUpdate/GeoIP/GeoLite2-ASN.mmdb')
reader1 = geoip2.database.Reader('C:/ProgramData/MaxMind/GeoIPUpdate/GeoIP/GeoLite2-City.mmdb')
reader2 = geoip2.database.Reader('C:/ProgramData/MaxMind/GeoIPUpdate/GeoIP/GeoLite2-Country.mmdb')

# CIDR/Net to be tested
network = ipaddress.ip_network("x.x.x.x/xx")
ip_address = network[0]

# Query data from the three databases for each IP address in the network
while ip_address in network:
    try:
        responseasn = reader.asn(ip_address)
        responseasnsystemnumber = reader.asn(ip_address).autonomous_system_number
        responseasnsystemorg = reader.asn(ip_address).autonomous_system_organization
        responseasnprefixlenght = reader.asn(ip_address)._prefix_len
        responsecity = reader1.city(ip_address)
        responsecityname = responsecity.city.name
        responsecountry = reader2.country(ip_address)
        responsecountryname = responsecountry.country.name
        responsecountryisocode = responsecountry.country.iso_code
        response_network = responseasn.network
    except geoip2.errors.AddressNotFoundError as e:
            response = None
            response_network = e.network

    # Print the results
    print(f"{ip_address}: ASN: {responseasnsystemnumber!r}, Org: {responseasnsystemorg!r}, Prefix: /{responseasnprefixlenght!r}")
    print(f"{ip_address}: City: {responsecityname!r}")
    print(f"{ip_address}: Country: {responsecountryname!r}")
    print(f"{ip_address}: Country Code: {responsecountryisocode!r}")
    # Move to next subnet
    ip_address = response_network[-1] + 1
```

The script updates the DB declared in GeoIP.conf file, since the exe file by default checks the path `C:\ProgramData\MaxMind\GeoIPUpdate` for this file, I suggest to don't change reader path, it is the path where the DB are saved after the update is finished.

I used MaxMind DB since was the only one that can check one supernet and give us all the networks inside that net.